# excel - how to create a "copy" of a worksheet in the same file, that still references to the original worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, links, cross-reference

excel - how to create a "copy" of a worksheet in the same file, that still references to the original worksheet

So I want it to behave like this

worksheet 1
worksheet 2 = copy of worksheet 1

When I change a value in a cell in workbook 1, it also changes in worksheet 2, cuz all the cells in worksheet 2 reference to the corresponding position in worksheet 1.

I can do it manually per column, but it's a lot of work. Would like an efficient solution.

Comment: Now I just drag this all around my workbook, but that's a lot of dragging... 

='huidige inhuringen'!A1

Comment: you can select the entire used area on worksheet1, copy, go to worksheet2, paste-link. That will fill worksheet2 with links to worksheet1. Is that what you mean?

Comment: ^^^^ If not, then please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1741328/edit) to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: hi Paul, if that creates links instead of copying values, yes that's an answer to my question

Comment: hi Paul, tested it, yes that's what I needed, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the worksheet to select move or copy, tick Create a copy. Use hyperlinks to connect two worksheets.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to create a separate copy. I want to create a linked copy. Not sure what you mean with hyperlinks.